# Wontfix status in commit message

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, commit, issue-tracking

I'm dealing with BitBucket issue tracking and one of the statuses is `wontfix`. The most common meaning of that status is that the issue may or may not be fixed in some future or that developers are not going to implement or again that is not fixable (e.g. some feature is very slow due to a complexity that cannot be improved).
BitBucket allows you to use commit messages to change the issue status (see [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html)).

My question is: given the "definition" of `wontfix`, how come there can be a commit with `wontfix` in the message? What can that commit be so that a change in the code leads to a `wontfix` status?

Comment: I would expect not a change in the code, but in documentation; perhaps an explanation of a known issue in the code and what makes it infeasible to change right now.

Comment: `wontfix` status may also because the report bug is not a bug actually, then the issue status will changed to `wontfix`. It's both ok to change issue status in commit message and the issue itself.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT but if it's not a bug the commit probably has nothing to do with that issue so referring to it is not really a best practice. I like Justin's answer, that makes real sense